# Android. Как получить изображение с камеры без превью

Tags: android, android-camera

Android 6.0+. Задача такая: нажимаем на кнопку, открывается камера и необходимо каждый кадр с камеры получать в Bitmap, потом этот Bitmap будет отдаваться Mobile Vision API для распознавания QR кода. Вопрос, как получать каждый кадр с камеры, не открывая превью, в нем нет необходимости. Не обязательно полностью писать решение, подскажите ссылки на ресурсы или подскажите алгоритм и необходимые классы. В android не силен, все примеры что я находил с использованием SurfaceHolder. 
P.S. Реализовывать буду только на android.hardware.camera2